# Problems running grunt tests for JHipster application

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, jhipster

When running "grunt test" all tests fail. All messages are like

`/app/account/password/password.directive.spec.js:9
        TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$httpBackend.flush'
)
            at C:/_PROJECT_SOURCE/my_app/src/test/javascript/spec
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8 0.0.0) Directive Tests  Password strength Should chan
ge the first 4 points of the strength bar FAILED
        Error: Plural Function not found for locale: de
            at MessageFormat (C:/_PROJECT_SOURCE/myapp/src/main/`

All 22 of 22 fails are the same. The "undefined is not an object" and then "Plural function not found". I Just added the german language and the whole app is working fine.
What do I miss?

Comment: You change $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('de');  ??